# Doctrine2 JOIN in Criteria

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using SF2.1 with Doctrine2

I have a model like this :

> Article 1.* ArticleCategory *.1 Category

In my Category Entity, I want to get all article related to $this , orderBy article.created and where article.published is true ,

I could do :

```
$articles = array();
foreach($this->getArticleCategory() as $art_cat){
    $article = $art_cat->getArticle();
    if($article->isPublished()) $articles[] = $article;
}
```

But It won't deal the orderBy, and it seems too heavy anyway...

The Criteria from Doctrine Collection is more appropriated but I don't see how to handle the relation table,

and I don't want to do this in a repository since it concerns a specific Category,

Any hints for me ?

Comment: Have you tried using annotations? @ORM\OrderBy({"created" = "ASC"})
Can you tell me what did contain "ArticleCategory"? Is-it only used to relate categories to articles?
Because if it's just used for that, you can create relations between Categories & articles and use annotations to add an orderBy

Comment: Hello ! thks for answer :) The ArticleCategory has some extra fields used for display preferences (position,featured,etc.) , Annotation doesn't seem to be a generic solution in this case because I might need another order in some conditions ...

Comment: Yes, I do agree! in that case it couldn't be done using annotations.

Comment: I think I'll end up doing it in the ArticleCategory Repository , passing the Category to some `getArticlesOrderDateAndPublished(Category $category)`

Answer (score 0):

if Article has:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="articles")
*/
private $categories;
```

and Category has:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="categories")
*/
private $articles;
```

(Assuming there's an article_category join table, according to Doctrine standards)

Then:

```
$articles = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Article')
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->join('a.categories', 'c')
        ->andWhere('c.id=:category_id')
        ->setParameter('category_id', $categoryId)
        ->andWhere('a.published=TRUE')
        ->orderBy('a.created')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Would bring the published articles for category identified by $categoryId, sorted by creation date.

Comment: If your join table is not article_category you might have to add an extra JoinTable annotation in Article

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to do this in the Entity, and we don't have access to repository there ... I thought it would be the right place to do it since it concerns a specific Category, maybe I'm wrong on this point ;)

Comment: Why don't you have access to the repository? If in the form (i.e. CategoryType) you still can have access to the repository.

Comment: I mean in the Entity class we don't have access to repository, no ?

Comment: You are absolutely right Vincent. I misunderstood the question, I guess. Let me think of a workaround.

Comment: Thks ! if you find something tell me cuz I'm stuck there ... :)

Comment: Have you found a workaround? I have the same question.